# Ошибка отправки на почту smtp.yandex.com

Tags: c#

какое может быть решение ошибки?

```
5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first
```

Код

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("lady.occur@yandex.ru", "Tom");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("vasilisa.tcheremushkina@yandex.ru");
MailMessage m = new MailMessage(from, to);
m.Subject = "Тест";
m.Body = "<h2>Письмо-тест работы smtp-клиента</h2>";
m.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.yandex.ru", 25);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("lady.occur@yandex.ru", "password");
smtp.Send(m);
MessageBox.Show("СМС ОТПРАВЛЕН");
```

Почты новорег - так что могу не беспокоиться :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66060/discussion-on-question-by------smtp-yandex-com).

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблемы в вашей комбинации

```
 MailAddress from = new MailAddress("lady.occur@yandex.ru", "Tom");
 MailAddress to = new MailAddress("vasilisa.tcheremushkina@yandex.ru");
 MailMessage m = new MailMessage(from, to);
```

Зачем? Если можно указать только кому, от кого будет выступать ваш логин?

вот рабочий пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SendMail("<h2>Письмо-тест работы smtp-клиента</h2>", "vasilisa.tcheremushkina@yandex.ru", "lady.occur@yandex.ru", "password");
        }
        public static void SendMail(string Mess,string Fto, string Flogin, string Fpass)
        {
            try
            {
                string body = Mess;
                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(Flogin);
                message.To.Add(Fto); 
                message.Subject = "TEST";
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Body = body;
                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient Smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.yandex.ru", 25);
                Smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                Smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Flogin, Fpass);
                Smtp.Send(message);
                Console.WriteLine("Сообщение отправлено: " + body);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ошибка отравки эмэйл" + DateTime.Now + " - " + ee.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если не сработает копайте в сторону логин пароля от lady.occur@yandex.ru, вы же с него собирались отправлять на василису? Точно не наоборот?

Comment: p.s. если нужно будет удалить ВАШИ ЛОГИН И ПАРОЛЬ(зачем вы его вообще сюда вписали) напишите, заменю словами login@ya.ru, password